# Как сделать копирование информации с сайта и отправка в telegtam Бот?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Первый раз работаю с telegram-api
Вообщем: Идея дневника в telegram. хочу чтобы бот брал информацию с сайта будто ДЗ звонки и т.п., и по команде "start" выводил мне ДЗ. Сам не могу додуматься, найти тоже. Мб есть мысли?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала определите точный список информации, которую нужно получать с сайта. Далее напишите код, который вернет вам, как пример, html-код нужной страницы. Исследуйте html-код. Получите из него нужные данные(по тэгам, классам, ид), как вариант сохраните данные в файл или базу данных. Можно получать(обновлять) данные по таймеру, например: раз в день. Используйте библиотеки requests, re, beautifulsoup4. 
Напишите бота, который будет отвечать на нужную команду, делая запрос в базу данных или файл (или запускаю функцию парсинга нужного сайта). Используйте библиотеки pytelegrambotapi, datetime. 
Должен ли бот отвечать только Вам или он может отвечать любому пользователю? 
Когда пишите вопросы, желательно вставлять код, потому что вряд ли найдется человек, который просто так напишет весь код за Вас.
Додумываться не надо, почитайте документацию по перечисленным библиотекам.

1. [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
2. [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
3. [beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
4. [pytelegrambotapi](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/0.3.0/)
5. [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
6. [telegram bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)